# Are there any feasibility studies or research regarding the possibility of using Jet A in tropical countries?

Tags: fuel, jet

Based on the ASTM D1655 standard specification for turbine fuels, the only difference between Jet A and Jet A-1 is the freezing point. Max [min?] -40 degrees Celsius (-40° F) for Jet A and max -47 degrees Celsius (-53° F) for Jet A-1.
Also, Jet A is widely available in the US (high latitudes).

From my understanding, if Jet A (with higher freezing point) is suitable in colder regions (e.g., the US), it should also be suitable in warmer regions (e.g., tropical countries), as it is already hard to reach -40 degrees Celsius (let alone -47 degrees Celsius) in tropical regions. *Assume that both have the same altitude.*

So, my questions are:

**Are there any feasibility studies or research regarding usage of Jet A fuel in tropical countries? Please share!**

and

**Could someone provide information of the cost production differences between Jet A and Jet A-1?**

Much appreciated guys!

Comment: What sort of "research regarding usage" are you looking for? Are you just trying to find out whether or not Jet-A is used in tropical countries, or are you looking for other information as well?

Comment: One thing is temperature on the ground, another temperature at the cruise level. Keep in mind it's worth climbing as long as it's getting colder.

Comment: And third thing is temperature at destination. And aircraft fuelling in a tropical country may be landing in an arctic one, or be overflying the North Pole, a couple of hours later. Do you want to complicate things by stocking multiple fuels?

Comment: @tanner-swett, for starter I want to know whether Jet A was used in tropical countries, and why don't they use it anymore. Like I said in my question, if Jet A is already used in colder region, it should be suitable in tropical region. So, why don't they use it? It is cheaper to produce (though I still don't know how much cheaper).

Comment: @jan-hudec, please explain "it's worth climbing as long as it's getting colder". Isn't it dangerous if your temperature at cruise level getting colder as it may cause the fuel freezing?

Comment: @JanHudec Yes, there might be some flights from tropical country to northern hemisphere, and for them you should use Jet A-1. However, my question is for domestic flight or international flight across tropical countries. And if it is worth the money, I don't see why we shouldn't stock multiple fuels. For that reason, I ask how much is price difference in producing Jet A and Jet A-1.

Comment: @arsenalist, the colder it gets, the more efficient the engines are. And note that the temperature at cruise level is almost always lower than the freezing point of the fuel. Average temperature at tropopause is -54°C. That's one of the reasons to use fuel-oil heat exchangers—minimum temperature for the aircraft is something like -67°C (IIRC that was for B777).